# Range of a log function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms

> Find the range of $f(x)=\ln(\frac{\sqrt{8-x^2}}{x-2})$

**My attempt :-**
$$f(x)=\ln(\frac{\sqrt{8-x^2}}{x-2})$$
$$=0.5\ln(8-x^2)-\ln(x-2)$$
After this I can't solve and not able to find the range.

Comment: Over what domain is $\ln$ defined?

Comment: **Hint** $:$ The domain of $f$ is $(2,2\sqrt 2).$

Comment: A possible approach could be trying to find the range of $g(x)=\frac{\sqrt{8-x^2}}{x-2}$ first. And then to check how it is transformed by the logarithm.

Comment: I find the domain but how to find the range using the domain

Comment: @AbhishekKumar what values does $f$ take at the endpoints? Also $f$ is continuous on its domain...

Comment: @gt6989b Continuous on its domain means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $\dfrac{8-x^2}{(x-2)^2}=y$

$\iff x^2(y+1)-4x+4y-8=0$

$x=\dfrac{2\pm\sqrt{52-(4y-2)^2}}2=2\pm\sqrt{13-(2y-1)^2}$

Now as $2<x<2\sqrt2$  and $2-\sqrt{13-(2y-1)^2}\le2$

$x=2+\sqrt{13-(2y-1)^2}$

$\iff2<2+\sqrt{13-(2y-1)^2}<2\sqrt2$

$2<2+\sqrt{13-(2y-1)^2}\implies13-(2y-1)^2\ne0\iff(2y-1)^2<13$

$2+\sqrt{13-(2y-1)^2}<2\sqrt2\implies13-(2y-1)^2<(2\sqrt2-2)^2$